# Stuck trying to parse XML using AJAX and Javascript with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

Re-edit of the InnerHtml to show how many Div's will be included in the finished code. Also a re-edit of the start function which now does not work and I'm not sure at what point I broke it.

```html
var fname = name;

function load()
{

var x = new XMLHttpRequest();

x.open ("GET", "file1.xml",true);

x.onreadystatechange = handleServerInput;

x.send();

xml =x.responseXML;

fname = xml.getElementsByTagName("name")[0];
name = fname.childNodes[0].data;
     

    

function handleServerInput()
{
 if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200)
    {
     function DisplayDiv()
  {
   var html = "";
   html+=   "  <div id = \"displayOuter\">";
   html+=   "  <div id = \"displayInner\">";
  html+=   "  <p id = \"fname\">";
    html+=   "  </p>";
     html+=   "  </div>";
     html+=   "  <div id = \"displayInner2\">";
     html+=   "  </div>";
     html+=   "  <div id = \"displayInner3\">";
     html+=   "  </div>";
    html+=   "  </div>";
    return html;
  } 
    function start()
    {
    document.body.innerHTML+=DisplayDiv(); 
    var displayOuterDiv = document.getElementById("displayOuter");
       displayOuterDiv.style.display= "block";
     
       
    var innerdiv = document.getElementById('displayInner');
         innerdiv.innerHTML = fname; 
           
         }
       
 //       alert (  this.responseText );
     
  
      }
 }
    
  }

 window.onload = load;
```

So I put the DisplayDiv function inside my handleServerInput function and that does imput the data to the HTML Div but only when it is set to false which I don't want. Can someone explain to me why this is? Here is an update of the code.

```html
var fname = name;

function load()
{

var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open ("GET", "file1.xml",false);
x.onreadystatechange = handleServerInput;
x.send();

function handleServerInput()
{

if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200)
    
{

    document.body.innerHTML+=DisplayDiv(); 
      div = document.getElementById('displayInner');
      div.innerHTML = fname; 
 
     }
     function DisplayDiv()
  {
   var html = "";
   html+=   "  <div id = \"displayInner\">";
    html+=   "     <p id = \"fname\">";
     html+=   "  </p>";
    html+=   "  </div>";
    return html;
  }
    
 }

xml =x.responseXML;

fname = xml.getElementsByTagName("name")[0];
name = fname.childNodes[0].data; 

}
```

Comment: it looks like you're getting the responseXML and trying to process it outside of the handleServerInput function - which wont work

Comment: Thanks but what is a way around this? How do I process it within handleServerInput?

Comment: _“In Firefox it is telling me [object HTMLParagraphElement]”_ – that’s likely because what you have in `fname` _is_ the reference to a paragraph element. It’s the part where you are trying to assign this element reference to the `innerHTML` of another element where you are going wrong. You can’t do that, this will only call the implicit toString method of the object, and what that returns simply _is_ `[object HTMLParagraphElement]`

Comment: x.responseXML will not have meaningful info until you receive your 200 response. If you use it immediately after x.send, it might be empty

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning `fname` before you use it. I assume you only want to use `x.responseXML` on a 200 response, so you should move

```
xml =x.responseXML;
fname = xml.getElementsByTagName("name")[0];
name = fname.childNodes[0].data;
```

into your if statement, somewhere before
`div.innerHTML = fname;`
happens

Comment: Thanks.  that does work however i have to press the button twice to bring up [object Element] on the HTML page then reload to bring in the XML data. Its only in Firefox it does this. Chrome and Safari it does nothing.

Comment: There are a few problems with your code, I would need to see it in context with the rest of the page. For example, each time you append innerHTML with DisplayDiv(), you will be adding an another div, but using the same id "displayInner". the id attribute should be unique, especially if you are going to use it in .getElementById()

Comment: Yeah you are right. There will be 3 divs contained in one outerdiv. The code above was a test to get the data imported. I am working on this so will post when I have sth to show.